# Header file inclusion and visibility in static library iOS

Tags: ios, xcode7, static-libraries

When a static library is created from an iOS project, in Lib.a file, does it have all the header files also bundled into it. Or should I mark all the header files that will be used by public header as private headers which then add all private files in /usr/local/include folder once the static library target is build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, nothing happens automatically. The normal process for static libraries is as follows:

- have a static library target in your project, so you can include the project in an app and verify functionality
- create a Run Script and Aggregate target so that you build one .a for iOS and one for the simulator, then "lipo" them together into one .a
- in the run script, copy the .a and all the necessary .h files into some folder you create

The folder is then what you distribute. The user links to the .a, and sets the Search Paths in their app project to point to the folder with your .a.

Comment: If my Xcode project with static library target depends upon many other static libraries, how should I create a framework which has all the static libraries into it, so that the end user don't have to manually add these libraries. Currently, I am using the libtool command to combine all the .a files into a single binary. All these dependent libraries and their headers are located outside the project folder, somewhere in the system. Do I have to include all the dependent static libraries headers into the project folder and mark them as private or project headers?

Comment: I only need the static library to support iPhone, not simulator. So, I am not using lipo command to created a Universal framework. Instead, I have to combine multiple static libraries into a single framework file, for which i am using libtool command.